# PHP - Append only if match found in txt-file

Tags: php, function

complete newbie to php here.
I have a simple application where I register different accesscodes. I've already written a function that checks the txt-file for duplicates, so that only new unique values are appended. This function works fine, see below.

```
function checkAccesscode($code)
{
    $file=fopen ("files/codes.txt", 'r');
       while ($string=fgets ($file))
      {
         if ($string!="")
            {
             $part=explode (";",$string);
             $input=trim($part[0]);

        if (stripos($input,$code)!==false)
        {
            return true;
        }
            }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
      }
}
```

Now, what I need is a similar, separate function which also checks for matches in a different txt-file (call it "codereg.txt"). Meaning that the code not only has to be unique, but it also has to be pre-registered in a different application/txt-file before it can be appended to its file.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Regards,
MadBer

Comment: Yes, it works on all lines. I've been trying to tweak it in several different ways, without stripos and different comparison operators. But the input either gets rejected or it registers inputs that it shouldn't.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a function that reads the entire files into arrays and searches those with [preg_grep()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-grep.php).

```
<?php

define("UNIQ", "uniqueCodes.txt");
define("PREREQ", "preregCodes.txt");

function checkCodes(string $code):bool {

    // Quote the search string to deal with regular expression special characters

    $code = preg_quote($code,'/');

    // Read the unique file. search with preg_grep(), return false if we get back a non-empty array

    $uniq = file(UNIQ, FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES | FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES);
    if (preg_grep("/^{$code}/i", $uniq)) {
        return false;
    };
    
    // Read the preregistered file and search with preg_grep(). Cast the result
    // to a boolean and return. An empty array casts to FALSE, otherwise TRUE

    $preq = file(PREREQ, FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES | FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES);
    return (bool)(preg_grep("/^{$code}/i", $preq));

}

$checks = ['abc123', 'abc124', 'abc126', 'abc200'];

foreach($checks as $check) {
    echo "Checking code $check:".(checkCodes($check)?"pass":"fail")."<br>";
}
```

Unique Codes:

```
abc123;first code
abc124;second code
abc125; third code
```

Preregistered codes:

```
abc123: a
abc124: b
abc125: c
abc200: d
abc201: e
```

Results:

```
Checking code abc123:fail  // non-unique code
Checking code abc124:fail  // non-unique code
Checking code abc126:fail  // unique, not pregistered
Checking code abc200:pass  // unique, pre-registered
```